# Implement a global generic notification component in React app

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am working on a React application and use react-redux and redux-thunk for integration with redux for state management.

I want to display a modal whenever I add a new entity. The ideal solution from my point of view seems to be:

1. In the action creator where I add the entity, the redux state should be updated with the notification message if the operation was succesfull
2. The main component of the app (The App component) should somehow listen to the redux state, and whenever a notifications message appears it should render the modal with the message.

I do not have an idea on how to implement the second point (how to subscribe the main component to state change and react accordingly).

On another note, there might be a better alternative to implement the notification component so I will gladly listen to alternative solutions as my exposure to front end development and React is quite limited.

Comment: have you seen this ? https://redux.js.org/api/store#subscribelistener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is that you probably want to display a "Snackbar" component (Example from [Material-ui](https://material-ui.com/components/snackbars/)), and not a dialog as you probably might have several entities created one after the other, and you don't want to flicker the dialogs to the user...

Regarding the redux store, I think you should have a specific part in your store to hold all the notifications (Array of notifications), And every time a message with new entity comes you add a notification to the array. And after some time (Say 5sec) you remove the notification from the array.

In the ui, your component should listen to this part of the store, and just display the Snackbars one after the other.

Comment: I'm actually a little bit confused on how to implement the whole subscription of the component to the state change

Comment: when working with redux you should use the `connect` method (Comes with redux), https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect to extract what you need from the store. any future changes to the store will auto-rerender your component

Comment: That was my problem ! Being new to react I forgot about the one way binding and how any state change cause the component to rerender.